# How to restrict users from download files uploaded to aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing a LMS in Laravel and uploading all the video files to aws s3 bucket and can play them using video js player. But problem is, users can download the video files, which I want to stop. Can anybody suggest me is it possible or not? If possible, can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Do you have any bucket policy set? Maybe its set for both Puts and Gets to everyone, instead  of only Puts?

Comment: Hello Marcin, I am actually new to AWS. So can you tell me how can I set the necessary bucket policy for what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in Amazon S3 are **private by default**.

However, if you wish students to make use of a file (eg a learning course video), you will need to grant access to the file. The best way to do this is by using [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provide time-limited access to a private object.

For example, the flow would be:

- A students **logs into the LMS**
- A student requests access to a course
- The LMS checks whether they are entitled to view the course (using your own business logic)
- If they *are* permitted to use the course, the LMS **generates a pre-signed URL** using a few lines of code, and returns the link in a web page (eg via an `<a>` tag).
- The student can access the content
- Once the expiry duration has passed, the pre-signed URL no longer works

However, during the period where the student has access to the file, **they can download it**. This is because access has been granted to the object. This is necessary because the web browser needs access to the object.

The only way to avoid this would be to provide courseware on a 'streaming' basis, where there is a continuous connection between the frontend and backend. This is not likely to be how your LMS is designed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions John. If I want to progress with the streaming basis, how can i achieve it? Can you give me a briefing please?

Comment: No idea! It's a bit like comparing YouTube (streaming) vs downloading a video file. The front-end of a streaming system needs to know how to retrieve and display information from the back-end. But people have figured out how to save streaming videos, so nothing is ever guaranteed! You might want to look at providers like Udemy to see how they address it.